# Apache mod_rewrite rule based on hostname

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to configure fancy URL for our application. We are using Apache as webserver.

When the user hit the URL `xyz.example.net/XYZ`, the app is working fine but the context root XYZ in this case is case sensitive and not easy to remember. I need some help to configure Apache to redirect the traffic to context root `/XYZ` if the hostname is `xyz.example.net` in the request and no context root is provided in the URL.  Can someone help me to write Apache mod_rewrite rule based on hostname?

```
xyz.example.net --> xyz.example.net/XYZ
```